# Is possible to create a temporary event in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I am working in a `Google App Engine` project that uses `Google Calendar`. The users can add courses in a shopping cart before actually purchasing them, and I need to show these events in the calendar. Is there any way to do so without (permanently) creating the events?

I would like to avoid creating the events and all the objects linking student and course together, which I would need to create in order to save the event id for posterior removal if the course is deleted from the shopping cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a temporary google calendar event that auto-deletes itself. You have to code it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It would be nice to be able to show something on the calendar without the need of being an event.

Comment: Sorry but to me it doesnt make sense.

Comment: Maybe not but would have been useful in my use case :-P I decided to create a calendar including all the courses as events, then just display the ones present in the shopping cart. Probably even simpler too.